# Pusher: How to set pusher client to intilizer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

**New Release from pusher**

```
require 'pusher'

pusher_client = Pusher::Client.new(
  app_id: '12242',
  key: '0d3ae65',
  secret: '88147',
  cluster: 'ap1',
  encrypted: true
)

pusher_client.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
  message: 'hello world'
})
```

Before that I was setting up configration globally like this

```
Pusher.app_id = ENV['PUSHER_APP_ID']
Pusher.key = ENV['PUSHER_KEY']
Pusher.secret = ENV['PUSHER_SECRET']
Pusher.logger = Rails.logger
Pusher.encrypted = true
Pusher.host = 'api-ap1.pusher.com'
Pusher.cluster = ENV['PUSHER_CLUSTER']

Pusher.trigger channels, 'new_message', self
```

Now How to add Pusher client configration to intializer so that I do not need to intialize it everytime??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the `pusher_client` client variable to `$pusher_client` or `PusherClient` - that way it will be accessible from the rest of your code (local variables are not).

Put this script in a new file in the `config/initializers` folder, which is autoloaded.

Comment: @mxple Thanks it works , can you explain why PusherClient is working ?

Comment: variables starting with lowercase are "local", they won't be available from other files. Those starting with a capital letter are "Constants", so they are availale.